# communication between two controllers in iOS MVC implementation

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, controller, communication

I've two different views which have two different controllers(firstVC and secondVC). Initially these two views appear in different viewcontrollers. Now, for some reason they have to appear in one viewcontroller and make some changes on one view when some action is done in second view, I need to create another viewcontroller(thirdVC).

Can I just add firstVC.view and secondVC.view on thirdVC's view and create some delegate methods of firstVC and secondVC to be implemented in thirdVC so that I do not need to make changes to existing firstVC and secondVC?

Answer (score 0):

A view controller whose view contains subviews managed by other view controllers is called a "container view controller". This is a supported pattern but you need to see [Implementing a Container View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81) and add the child view controllers to their parent container view controller in addition to adding their views as subviews.

This ensures that 1. the parent controller retains the child controllers so that their views do not send messages to deallocated controllers and 2. correctly sends framework messages like rotation events are sent to the child controllers. If you do not use these view controller containment methods your child controllers will eventually break in surprising ways.